# Determine the coordinate of the point where line and circle collide/intersect - how to solve for x

Tags: circles

I would like to determine the point $C$ in this image:

[image]

(assume I have radius value).

After the hours of research and refreshing some memories from school days, I've got:

Please assume...

Point: (xCoordinate, yCoordinate):

A (center): $(x_0,y_0)$

B: $(x_1,y_1) $

Plugging them into equation of circle

$$x^2 + \left(y_0 + \left( \frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}\right) (x-x_0)\right)^2 = r^2$$

Now how can I solve for $x$? I would like to have the equation that starts with "$x=$".

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1):

Because the point $C=(x,y)$ is lies on a line through $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$, it is of the form
$$(x,y)=(x_0+t(x_1-x_0),y_0+t(y_1-y_0))$$
for some real number $t$. In order for $C$ to lie on the circle, we must have that
$$(t(x_1-x_0))^2+(t(y_1-y_0))^2=r^2,$$
and hence $$t=\frac{r}{\sqrt{(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2}}.$$
Thus, the $x$-coordinate of $C$ is
$$x=x_0+\frac{r(x_1-x_0)}{\sqrt{(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assuming the coordinates of unknown point are $(X,Y)$, solve these two equations simultaneously: $$(Y-y_0)^2+(X-x_0)^2=r^2,~~~Y=\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}(X-x_0)-y_0$$

Comment: helpful hint! + 1